# How to put AdMob Banner in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, admob

I am creating an game in SpriteKit, and I don't know how to use AdMob banner in SpriteKit. I know how to use with Swift where you drag the view to your storyboard, and etc... But once again, Can anyone help me to use it in SpriteKit?

> Getting this error when applying to place banner.

**To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ ***!********'" ];**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is the exact same as with `UIKit`, except that you have to position it programmatically. Also make sure that this code goes in `viewDidLoad` in your `GameViewController`. Just add this line in:

```
BannerAd.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
```

All in all you banner ad code should look something like this:

```
var BannerAd = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
BannerAd.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
BannerAD.delegate = self
BannerAD.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-##/##"
BannerAD.rootViewController = self

let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "*************************"]

BannerAD.loadRequest(request)
view.addSubview(BannerAd)
```

Comment: Do I need to specify a variable like: var bannerView: GADBannerView?

Comment: @Robert It assumes the variable type since I explicitly set it when it's declared. If that doesn't make sense I can explain it to you

Comment: Ok. But Now for: BannerAd.rootViewController = self it is saying that "Cannot assign value of type MYGame(which is a skscene) to type UIViewController?

Comment: @Robert Is that code in your GameViewController? Or a scene? It should be in your GameViewController

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for your help. It Worked

Comment: I am getting an error. Check out my Updated Question

Comment: @Robert That just makes it so your device gets test ads. Just add that code to the array of test devices (the one that has kGADSimulatorID in it. You should take the code down. It's private to your device

Comment: it still doesnt show any ads . you know what is going on?

Comment: @Robert Try messing around with the y-coordinate of the CGRect. Maybe I placed it incorrectly

Comment: can this show it in SKSCENE? I played with y-coord. but nothing is shown. I wanted to show on skscene

Comment: @Robert The GameViewController displays all the scenes so putting the banner on it effectively puts it on all the scenes. As for the issue, I believe it's because I forgot to add the line of code that actually adds the banner to the view. Take a look at the updated answer

Comment: Thank you once again. One last question. Write now it doesnt show real ads, but its just show nice job! Sample ad. Will it show when the app is published?

Comment: @Robert Yes it will, just not on the device(s) that you set for test ads.