# How to present interstitials to an SKScene in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, admob, skscene

I´m continuously trying to implement an interstitial to a view in my project but I always get the same error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Start' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'" when I make the call defined below.

Does someone know how to implement them in SprtieKit because I only found resources for Swift?

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class Start: SKScene, GADInterstitialDelegate{

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    interstitial.delegate = self
    if self.interstitial.isReady {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("quitToLevel:")), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "quitToLevelID"), object: nil)
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self) //->Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Start' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'
     }else{
        print("add didn´t load")
    }
 }
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put AdMob Banner in SpriteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688890/how-to-put-admob-banner-in-spritekit)

Comment: It´s not a duplicate because I´m asking for an interstitial, not a banner. @El Tomato

Comment: I'm aware of that.  So?

Comment: @ElTomato you're making the claim that it's a possible duplicate. The polite thing to do would be reasoning, rationalisation, explanation and justifications of your claim.

Comment: Thanks @Confused !